# Terminate due to time out in hacker rank "Array Manipulation"

Tags: java

Guys i am trying to solve  ["Arrays Manipulation" in hacker rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem)

which is

You are given a list(1-indexed) of size , initialized with zeroes. You have to perform  operations on the list and output the maximum of final values of all the  elements in the list. For every operation, you are given three integers ,  and  and you have to add value  to all the elements ranging from index  to (both inclusive).

For example, consider a list  of size . The initial list would be  = [, , ] and after performing the update  = , the new list would be  = [, , ]. Here, we've added value 30 to elements between indices 2 and 3. Note the index of the list starts from 1.

and my solution is

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n = in.nextInt();
         List<Long> arr = new ArrayList<Long>(Collections.nCopies(n, new Long(0)));
         int m = in.nextInt();
         for(int a0 = 0; a0 < m; a0++){
             int a = in.nextInt();
             int b = in.nextInt();
             int k = in.nextInt();
             
             for(int i=a-1;i<=b-1;i++){
               arr.set(i, arr.get(i)+k);
             }
         }
         in.close();
         System.out.println(Collections.max(arr));
    }
}
```

any help ... why i am getting "terminate due to timeout"  ???

Comment: you are getting "terminate due to timeout" because your solution is too slow. By the way - I see you are not changing the size of your `arr`, so why use `ArrayList<Long>` instead of `long[]`? Object creation really slows down this kind of programs tested by online judges

Comment: @Fureeish any suggestions to make it more fast ?

Comment: If your code produces the correct output but it appears to be too slow, you should post your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow. I'd start with replacing the `ArrayList<Long>` with `long[]` and maybe `Scanner` with a faster input method

Comment: Your solution is using a naive, brute-force approach. I can't think about an efficient solution right now but basically this type of problem invites you to record/store the information in a clever way that prevents you from explicitly traversing the data structure on every update

Comment: @Fureeish the real problem here is the complexity of the solution, not its implementation details. The algorithm is intrinsically slow (quadratic) regardless of how it is implemented.

Comment: I added an optimal linear solution based on some ideas I found on Google, you can check it out.

Answer (score 4):

### Optimal linear algorithm

I'll be honest, I didn't come up with the idea myself, I first read a few things which made me figure out the optimal algorithm in linear time. Basically, the idea is record the value `+k` at index `a` and value `-k` at index `b` at each query. It then allows you to calculate the total value of each cell after the `m` queries by simply calculating the running sum (starting from the left) of the array. Pretty smart, I'm sad it's not an idea of my own !

Here's a solution in Scala with which I passed all HackerRank's tests:

```scala
object Solution {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val lines       = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines()
        val Array(n, m) = lines.next().split(' ').map(_.toInt)

        val arr = Array.ofDim[Int](n)

        for (line <- lines) {
            val Array(low, high, k) = line.split(' ').map(_.toInt)
            arr(low  - 1) += k
            if (high < arr.length) arr(high) -= k
        }

        var runningSum = BigInt(0)
        var max = BigInt(0)

        for (i <- arr) {
            runningSum += i
            max = runningSum.max(max)
        }

        println(max)
    }
}
```

### Other idea for the reference

I originally thought about using a data structure that may be useful here. It is called [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). With this data structure, you can store and query a set of intervals in logarithmic time.

My idea was that if you managed to store the update queries as intervals associated with a value (the amount to add to each element of the interval), you could solve the problem in `O(m log n + m)`, which is already much faster than the naive `O(m * n)` solution, but still not as fast as the above linear solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Constraints-**

3≤≤10^7

1≤≤2⋅10^5

1≤≤≤

0≤≤10^9

**Why your brute force solution will not work?**

Today generation system can perform 10^8 operation in one second. keep this in mind you have to process N=10^7 input per query in worse case. so if you use your solution with O(NM) complexity it has to handle (10^7 *10 ^5)= 10^12 operation in worse case (which can not be computed in 1 sec at all)

That is the reason you will get the time out error for your brute force solution.
So you need to optimise your code which can be done with the help of prefix sum array.

instead of adding k to all the elements within a range from a to b in an array, accumulate the difference array

Whenever we add anything at any index into an array and apply prefix sum algorithm the same element will be added to every element till the end of the array.

ex- n=5, m=1, a=2 b=5 k=5

```
    i     0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6   //take array of size N+2 to avoid index out of bound
  A[i]    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Add k=5 to at a=2

A[a]=A[a]+k  // start index from where k element should be added

```
     i    0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6 
   A[i]   0     0     5     0     0     0     0
```

now apply prefix sum algorithm

```
     i    0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6 
  A[i]    0     0     5     5     5     5     5
```

so you can see K=5 add to all the element till the end after applying prefix sum but we don't have to add k till the end. so to negate this effect we have to add -K also after b+1 index so that only from [a,b] range only will have K element addition effect.

A[b+1]=A[b]-k  // to remove the effect of previously added k element after bth index.
that's why adding -k in the initial array along with +k.

```
    i    0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6 
  A[i]   0     0     5     0     0     0    -5
```

Now apply prefix sum Array

```
    i    0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6 
  A[i]   0     0     5     5     5     5     0
```

You can see now K=5 got added from a=2 to b=5 which was expected.
Here we are only updating two indices for every query so complexity will be O(1).

Now apply the same algorithm in the input

```
         # 0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6    //taken array of size N+2 to avoid index out of bound
5 3      # 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1 2 100  # 0    100    0   -100    0     0     0       
2 5 100  # 0    100   100  -100    0     0   -100
3 4 100  # 0    100   100    0     0  -100   -100
```

To calculate the max prefix sum, accumulate the difference array to  while taking the maximum accumulated prefix.

After performing all the operation now apply prefix sum Array

```
    i      0.....1.....2.....3.....4.....5.....6 
  A[i]     0     100   200  200   200   100    0
```

Now you can traverse this array to find max which is 200.
traversing the array will take O(N) time and updating the two indices for each query will take O(1)* number of queries(m)

overall complexity=O(N)+O(M) 
                  = O(N+M)

it means = (10^7+10^5) which is less than 10^8 (per second)

**Here is the code:**

```
static long arrayManipulation(int n, int[][] queries) {

        long outputArray[] = new long[n + 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
            int a = queries[i][0];
            int b = queries[i][1];
            int k = queries[i][2];
            outputArray[a] += k;
            outputArray[b+1] -= k;
        }
        long max = getMax(outputArray);
        return max;
    }

    /**
     * @param inputArray
     * @return
     */
    private static long getMax(long[] inputArray) {
        long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            sum += inputArray[i];
            max = Math.max(max, sum);
        }
        return max;
```

**Note:** If searching for **[video tutorial](https://youtu.be/hDhf04AJIRs)** , you must check it out **[here](https://youtu.be/hDhf04AJIRs)** for detailed explanation.